# Can Comcast see me naked?

Tags: windows, networking, webcam, desktop-computer

I got a new laptop within the last month or so and have started my own adult entertainment website. I have a TON of success on here, but that's besides the point.  Recently I have had more Comcast guys show up at my door asking me if I need all sorts of work done. They seem kind of like creeps and I think they are only doing this because they are secretly viewing my shows online. Can Comcast see me naked? What can I do to prevent them from doing so?  I am sorry but I did not see any questions like this one on here already.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? I think it's completely legitimate.

Comment: Because downvoters don't work at Comcast

Comment: How are you sharing your videos?  Do you record them locally and upload them to your website or are you live streaming?   What kind of a connection is used to share the video?

Comment: This question seems too broad, and I don't think it's to do with computer hardware or software. It would be better on the security SE maybe

Comment: This identical question was asked many weeks ago, so I suspect somebody is trolling the site.

Answer (score 5):

If you are hosting your videos at your home, or if you are uploading the videos over an unencrypted connection, then it is certainly possible that your ISP has access to view the videos you are using. To prevent this, make sure you are uploading your videos over an encrypted connection (HTTPS) only.